# jQuery getScript method's internal process

Tags: jquery, getscript

I am trying to understand the internal process of getScript. I am aware that it uses $.get method interally.I was thinking that jQuery puts a script tag reference into the DOM for being able execute that js file but I couldn't find script references of loaded scripts by getScript in the DOM .

So how does jQuery execute loaded scripts without script tag references in the DOM?

`$.getScript('gallery.js')` is exactly same thing with `$('<script src="gallery.js">').appendTo('body')` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This is the interesting part in the source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/script.js).

jQuery seems to just receive the text and evaluates it in global scope:

```
converters: {
    "text script": function( text ) {
        jQuery.globalEval( text );
        return text;
    }
}
```

In case you load the script from a different domain, jQuery adds a new `script` tag:

```
head.insertBefore( script, head.firstChild );
```

but removes it once the code was loaded:

```
// Remove the script
if ( head && script.parentNode ) {
    head.removeChild( script );
}
```

Comment: Even jQuery remove added scripts. Try this $('<script src="sample.js">').appendTo('body');

Answer (score 5):

Luke, [use](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/bb7d98f018c284a27b286a819238bac5541aad5e/src/ajax.js#L268) [the](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/bb7d98f018c284a27b286a819238bac5541aad5e/src/ajax.js#L248) [source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/bb7d98f018c284a27b286a819238bac5541aad5e/src/ajax.js#L361).

<sub>(note these links are to an old commit)</sub>

Comment: @ZMorek yes. This answer is 18 months old, and jQuery has continued active development. I've updated to link to a revision from back then.

Comment: @MattBall - can/would you update it again please? :)

Comment: You _found_ the source, but I don't know that you've _used_ the source to answer "how". And that's really the most important part of the source: the _using_. Anybody can just find them (though I have to admit I'm really happy that you did). (apologies [to Jerry](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0697648/characters/nm0000632))